# Set axis position between subplots with plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

In a python project, I've got a subplot like this with plotly:
[Subplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHBWU.png)

But I want that y axis labels to be between the two subplots.
I searched on internet, but didn't find anything close to my problem.  Can anyone tell me how to solve my problem ?

Comment: Update your post with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Reproducible examples are not answers, please edit your question and post your code and current output. I have an answer that improves on your code and moves the left y-axis to the center.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little reproductible example:

```py
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objs as go

lec = [1, 2, 1, 5, 2]
ham = [2, 1, 2, 2, 1]
categories = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, shared_yaxes=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=lec, y=categories, orientation="h", name="Lec"), row=1, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Lec", row=1, col=1, autorange="reversed")
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=ham, y=categories, orientation="h", name="Ham"), row=1, col=2)
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Ham", row=1, col=2)
fig.update_layout(template="plotly_dark")

fig.show()
```